# Pandas adding Time column to Date index

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, reshape, timedelta

I have a dataframe, Date index type is *Timestamp*, Time column is *datetime.Time*:

```
            Time  Value
Date
2004-05-01  0:15  3.58507  
2004-05-02  0:30  3.84625
              ...
```

How do I convert it to:

```
                    Value
Date
2004-05-01 0:15     3.74618
2004-05-01 0:30     3.58507
2004-05-01 0:45     3.30998
```

I wrote a code which does work, but it's not very pythonic:

```
ind = frame.index.get_level_values(0).tolist()
tms = frame['Time']
new_ind = []
for i in range(0, len(ind)):
    tm = tms[i]
    val = ind[i] + timedelta(hours=tm.hour, minutes=tm.minute, seconds=tm.second)
    new_ind.append(val)

frame.index = new_ind
del frame['Time']
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can first convert column `Time` [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html), then add to `index`, [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) column `Time` and if necessary set index `name`:

```
df.Time = pd.to_timedelta(df.Time + ':00', unit='h')
df.index = df.index + df.Time
df = df.drop('Time', axis=1)
df.index.name = 'Date'
print (df)
                       Value
Date                        
2004-05-01 00:15:00  3.58507
2004-05-02 00:30:00  3.84625
```

If column `Time` is `datetime.time` for me works cast to `string` first (if necessary add `:00`):

```
df.Time = pd.to_timedelta(df.Time.astype(str), unit='h')
df.index = df.index + df.Time
df = df.drop('Time', axis=1)
df.index.name = 'Date'
print (df)
                       Value
Date                        
2004-05-01 00:15:00  3.58507
2004-05-02 00:30:00  3.84625
```